# RegexpError: end pattern with unmatched parenthesis

Tags: ruby, regex

I have 
list of brand  as a string 
 `brands = 'Lawrence Bill Lawrence OBL Billdidit Binson Bitchstraps Biyang Black Arts'` it pretty large

and what i want it find if my string includes one of them

```
my_str = ' txt txt OBL txt'

my_str[(/#{brands}/)]
```

but i have got `RegexpError: end pattern with unmatched parenthesis`

what i'm have done wrong?

Comment: Escape the #brands contents.

Comment: As @WiktorStribiżew said: `my_str[/#{Regexp.escape brands}/]` (also note that parentheses are superfluous.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to “find if my string includes one of them,” you do not need regular expressions:

```
brands = %w|BAR FOO|
my_str = ' txt txt BAR txt'
brands.any? { |brand| my_str.include? brand }
#⇒ true
brands.detect { |brand| my_str.include? brand }
#⇒ "BAR"
```

Unfortunately, this will match `BAR` in string like `text FOOBARBAZ text`. To avoid that:

```
my_str =~ Regexp.union brand.map(&:Regexp.escape).map { |e| "\b#{e}\b" }
```

In fact, since `Regexp.union` escapes the strings itself, it should be written as:

```
my_str =~ Regexp.union brand.map { |e| "\b#{e}\b" }
```

For those too lazy to understand the plain English:

```
my_str.scan Regexp.union brand.map { |e| "\b#{e}\b" }
```

Comment: i want to return brand name if it matched, not just `true`

Comment: it works,but if i have `my_str ='maraca Meinl MSM4'`, and use `brands.detect { |brand| my_str.include? brand }` it gives me `MSM` except `Meinl` Meinl and  MSM -my brands.

Comment: Do you mind to read the answer instead of blindly copy-pasting the snippets found?

Answer (score 0):

```
pattern = Regexp::union(brands.strip.split(/\W+/))
# => "/Lawrence|Bill|OBL|Billdidit|Binson|Bitchstraps|Biyang|Black|Arts/"

my_str.match(pattern)
# => #<MatchData "OBL">

my_str.scan(pattern)
# => ["OBL"]
```

Comment: Consider using semantically correct `Regexp.union` instead of `join('|')`.

Comment: @mudasobwa: Thanks for the hint. I changed my answer.

Comment: Also I would split on `/\W+/` instead of single `/\W/`, to avoid empty results for e. g. “You see, commas.”